# Mathematical structures textbook recommendation

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am busy doing an undergraduate course called "Fundamentals of Mathematics". It is not well-defined as there is no syllabus nor recommended textbook (there are lectures and notes), but the course introduces one to quite complicated theoretical aspects of mathematics. I would like to find a textbook for this course which would help me to understand what is being taught.

*What we have already covered or are covering:*

Magmas and unitary magmas, preorders and orders, semilattices and lattices, semigroups, monoids, closure operators, equivalence relations (I am familiar with the definition of an equivalence relation, but I can revise the place a quotient set has in a canonical factorization of a map and so on), Russell Paradox, Boolean algebra, cardinality, categories, morphisms (including monomorphisms, endomorphisms and isomorphisms), sub-algebras, set-theoretic definition of natural numbers.

*What I predict we will still cover, based on the notes:*

Canonical factorization of homomorphisms, quotient algebras, classical algebraic structures, quotient groups, rings and modules, semirings and semimodules, pointed categories, products and coproducts, direct sums, free algebras and free semimodules.

I already have a textbook called "Introduction to Abstract Algebra", but this focuses on, and goes into depth about, algebraic structures, as opposed to briefly constructing the many structures mentioned above.

Comment: I had a similar experience of being introduced to many mathematical concepts in a rapid-fire succession. This doesn't really answer your question, but I recomend reading the wikipedia articles on the objects you want to know more about. They are quite good, and often give some context for why you should care...

Comment: With the content you are listing, I would not say your 'fundamentals of mathematics' course is not well defined.  I would say it is defined pretty badly: too many advanced structures, too many actual fundamentals not covered.  The cognitive dissonance I get when statements like "I am familiar with the definition of an equivalence relation" are followed by " semirings and semimodules, pointed categories, products and coproducts" is pretty hard to express.

Comment: To be sure you should ask the teacher. However,  i believe Serge Lang "Algebra" probably covers it all (which I suggest you to look up anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Try books by Serge Lang, Spivak, and in that direction, I mean I'm throwing names out there because I have these books and the amount of sheer detail is staggering, this a start, branch out from here, locate common publishers and cross-check user reviews